How do I scroll to a DocumentNode or get it's vertical offset in flutter super_editor
I am using super_editor particularly it's SuperReader
I am able to target the DocumentNode I want to scroll to using it's id.
But how do I scroll to that particular document node? Or how can I get the offset position of that DocumentNode?

Which version of Super Editor are you using? Which approaches have you tried?

Hey @SuperDeclarative I was able to scroll to the desired node, I have answered this question with my solution. Please add new answer if there a better way to achieve this. Also, I am now interest to scroll to a particular marker in the desired node. Please let me know if that is possible.

I am currently using super_editor 0.3.0-dev.2 and I was able to achieve this  with this method:
final desiredNode = _doc.getNodeById(<node-id>)

final nodeStartingPoint = _getBeforeOffsets(_doc, node);


final desiredNodeOffset = nodesBefore + node.beginningPosition.offset;


Method to get previous nodes offsets:
double _getBeforeOffsets(MutableDocument doc, ParagraphNode node) {
  final nodesBefore = <DocumentNode>[];
  DocumentNode currentNode = node;
  DocumentNode? previousNode = doc.getNodeBefore(currentNode);
  while (previousNode != null) {
    nodesBefore.add(previousNode);
    currentNode = previousNode;
    previousNode = doc.getNodeBefore(currentNode);
  }

  return nodesBefore.fold<double>(
    0.0,
    (previousValue, element) =>
        previousValue +
        (element is ParagraphNode ? element.endPosition.offset : 0.0),
  );
}

Now I also want see if it is possible to get the position of a particular Marker, I will update it here if I manage to achieve it.

In your question you said that you were trying to scroll to a node, but your posted solution is looking up a character offset in a string. Seems unrelated. Have you looked at the DocumentLayout API that Super Editor provides? Along with the SingleColumnDocumentLayoutComponent? Those provide UI geometry queries.
